# Filter a signal by the value of another signal

Tags: elm

I want to create a filtered `Signal` for mouse position. It should update when a mouse button is down, or the mouse transitions from "not down" to "down".

I came up with this function. It works, but using three anonymous functions doesn't seem right. Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

```
mouseDownPosition: Signal (Int, Int)
mouseDownPosition = 
  Signal.map2 (\(x, y) isDown -> (x, y, isDown)) Mouse.position Mouse.isDown
  |> Signal.filter (\(x, y, isDown) -> isDown) (0, 0, False)
  |> Signal.map (\(x, y, isDown) -> (x, y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Library function

There is a utility library for signals called [signal-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0) (full disclosure: I'm the author of that library), which has a function for just this: [`keepWhen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/Signal-Extra#keepWhen)`: Signal Bool -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a`.

> [...] filter that keeps events from the `Signal a` as long as the `Signal Bool` is true.

## Implementation

If you're wondering, the [implementation](https://github.com/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/blob/1960683761aafab9af961b2be47960d81a871ac0/src/Signal/Extra.elm#L315-L320) does almost the same as you wrote yourself, but there is a subtle difference!

```
keepWhen : Signal Bool -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a
keepWhen boolSig a aSig =
  zip boolSig aSig
  |> sampleOn aSig
  |> keepIf fst (True, a)
  |> map snd
```

The `zip` is just a `Signal.map2 (,)` to combine the two signals. The `keepIf` is an old (IMHO clearer) name for `Signal.filter`. So that's all basically the same. But after zipping the two signals together, there is a `sampleOn`. That's there so the result of filtering is a signal that only updates when the original value signal `aSig` updates, and doesn't update when the `boolSig` updates.

## Alternative semantics

There is another filter called [`sampleWhen`](https://github.com/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/blob/1960683761aafab9af961b2be47960d81a871ac0/src/Signal/Extra.elm#L322-L333)`: Signal Bool -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a`, which has the description:

> A combination of `Signal.sampleOn` and `keepWhen`. When the
>   first signal becomes `True`, the most recent value of the second signal
>   will be propagated.

This alternative matches with the code that you wrote, but it doesn't match your description "Its value should change only when a mouse button is down".

Now it's up to you to figure out which behaviour you were really looking for :)

Comment: Thanks! You are right, my description was a little imprecise (I've updated it). Right now it's expedient to handle `isDown` and `position` updates together so my solution and `sampleWhen` work well. At some point I will handle `isDown` updates separately, so I will use `keepWhen`, or add `sampleOn` to my function.

Answer (score 2):

I like @joews solution better but just for the sake of an alternative, here is another version:

```
mouseDownPosition: Signal (Int, Int)
mouseDownPosition = 
  Signal.map2 (\p d -> if d then Just p else Nothing) Mouse.position Mouse.isDown
  |> Signal.filterMap identity (0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst posting the question I worked out how to avoid anonymous functions. I have a feeling there is a more elegant solution, though.

```
mouseDownPosition: Signal (Int, Int)
mouseDownPosition = 
  Signal.map2 (,) Mouse.position Mouse.isDown
  |> Signal.filter snd ((0, 0), False)
  |> Signal.map fst
```